# df.set_index => Index data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have successfully created a `DataFrame df` from pandas.
However, `df.set_index('Time')` throws `ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional` and cannot proceed further.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Time dtime Open Close High Low Volume'.split()])
df = df.astype({'Time':'datetime64[ms]', 'Open':float, 'High':float, 'Low':float, 'Close':float, 'Volume':float})
df.set_index('Time')

<but Error occurred...>
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional
```

<`print(df['Time'])`>

```
              Time
0    1646498160000
1    1646498220000
2    1646498280000
3    1646498340000
4    1646498400000
```

what's wrong? Why does 'set_indexs' throw an error?

#==============================================
#well done code example in my other modules

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns='Time Open High Low Close'.split())
df = df.astype({'Time':'datetime64[ms]', 'Open':float, 'High':float, 'Low':float, 'Close':float})
df.set_index('Time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong is first line, need remove `[]` for avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time dtime Open Close High Low Volume'.split()])
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(  'Time',),
            ( 'dtime',),
            (  'Open',),
            ( 'Close',),
            (  'High',),
            (   'Low',),
            ('Volume',)],
           )

df = pd.DataFrame(columns='Time Open High Low Close'.split())
print (df.columns)
Index(['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem. I'm sorry for late reply.